# LINQ to SQL - Association lost when I turn ObjectTrackingEnabled off

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000

I am using Linq-to-SQL (C# 3.5) to read two tables, house and county, from my database (SQL Server 2000). House has a CountyID column that matches an ID column in the county table. The County table has ID and CountyName columns.There is no association in the database - I added it in the dbml file. (Parent class = County, Child class = House)

Now I can query the House table and get the county name as house.County.CountyName - just what I want.

This works great unless I set EnableObjectTracking false. I get approx 3X performance improvement but the County child object in House is null.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set EnableObjectTracking to false, you also turn off lazy loading child entities as you have noticed. MSDN says...

> Deferred loading requires object
>   tracking. Only the following three
>   modes are valid:
>
> ObjectTrackingEnabled = false.
>   DeferredLoadingEnabled is ignored and
>   inferred to be false. This behavior
>   corresponds to a read-only
>   DataContext.
>
> ObjectTrackingEnabled = true.
>   DeferredLoadingEnabled = false. This
>   situation corresponds to a DataContext
>   that allows users to load an object
>   graph by using LoadWith directives,
>   but it does not enable deferred
>   loading.
>
> Both are set to true. This is the
>   default.

You can use the `LoadWith` method to populate your child entities if you want to keep Object Tracking Disabled.  Please see MSDN for more information on the [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx)